# Connect a PC to PSTN network

Tags: voip

I have a land-line phone through my ISP. I use it to call land-line phones free of charge like phones in Europe etc. what I want to do is that I want to use this service from any PC so I can call any land-line phone. 
I'm a newbie in this but what I understood so far is that I need to install some kind of VOIP server on PC and connect that server to my home router.
The VOIP server will provide me with user name/password that I can use on a VOIP client app on any PC. So that I can authenticate myself from anywhere in VOIP server and call for free.
I hope I've explained clearly what I want to do.
Thanks alot for any help or advice that could put me on the right way.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better of asking this question on serverfault.com (you can also migrate this question to there by editing this question)

Comment: Would you please tell me how can I migrate it to serverfault.com?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking it was easy to do yourself :/ ehrm perhaps it would be quicker to delete this one and ask your question again on serverfault (sorry again)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify if you preferred Windows or Linux, but if Linux is OK for you I'd recommend you look into Asterisk (http://www.asterisk.org/)

While a little daunting at first, it will allow you to do exactly what you want:
* it is your VoIP server
* you connect it up to your "trunk" (the line provided by your ISP for calls)
* you put it on your network
* and you can basically authenticate to it using a softphone client on your PC or other device from anywhere and make/receive calls on the line provided by your ISP

With some of the GUI frontends, like FreePBX, basic setup is not too daunting.

Dunno though how you'd do this on a Windows box, I am not familiar with equivalent Windows technical solutions.